# Null Pointer Exception for my Java project

Tags: java

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, I keep getting

```
exception in thread main java.lang.NullPointerException
```

on the following part :

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_AANTAL; i++) {
        if (templates[i][0].length() == 0) {
            System.out.print("Geef de naam van je nieuwe template : ");
            templates[i][0] = Input.readString();
            System.out.print("Voer de nieuwe template in : ");
            templates[i][1] = Input.readString();
            break;
            }
        if (i == (MAX_AANTAL - 1)) {
            System.out.println("Er kan geen template meer toegevoegd worden");
            break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("test");
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `MAX_AANTAL` and in which line you get exception?

Comment: Something is `null`.

Comment: I'm guessing you never initialized the elements of the `templates` array (or it's child arrays).

Comment: Which line exactly? To just guess I might suggest, it's that `if (templates[i][0].length() == 0) {` should be `if (templates[i][0] == null || templates[i][0].length() == 0) {`

Comment: MAX_AANTAL is a finalstring set to 10, and I'm getting the exception at the line "if (templates[i][0].length() == 0) {"

Comment: @Yoda Max_aantal translates to "highest number"

Comment: One of the following is `null` :  `MAX_AANTAL`, `templates[][]` (`templates` may not be null, but one of the values inside may be), `Input`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Elliott Frisch , thank you very much !

Comment: For future reference for questions like this - post the code that initializes the variables too, post the exception/error with stack trace/line number - and say which line of the code that corresponds to!

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Comment: please close the post if the response i ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, I guessed correctly in that the initialization code was meant to occur here -

```
if (templates[i][0].length() == 0)
```

and thus, it should have been

```
if (templates[i][0] == null || templates[i][0].length() == 0)
```

Comment: Yes indeed! Again, thank you very much, too bad I can't upvote your answer (need 15 reputation for some reason).

Comment: I see, didn't noticed that. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialized your array : `templates`

Try the following:

```
String[][] templates = new String[MAX_AANTAL][2];
```